# Can I put JS scripts above footer instead of below footer before </body> tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a website which is built with django.

Problem: we have >50 pages currently and exactly identical footer HTML code on each of those pages. I am getting tired of having to edit all those pages when adding a little change to the footer.

Possible solution: inserting the footer directly in the django base page.

Potential problems: if I insert the footer in the base page, all the individual JS scripts between the footer and the  tag would be lost - clearly those scripts are page specific. So could I have the specific JS scripts BEFORE the footer? This would allow the footer to go in the base nice and easily, but I'm not sure I can do this. Would moving the scripts before the footer be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Was about to post an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367155/how-do-i-modify-an-element-within-an-object, but then you deleted it - use `padStart` instead of a conditional

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have scripts above the HTML footer. This has a potential downside that you would have to wait for the scripts to be fetched and ran before your footer HTML is rendered - but that's unlikely to be a problem unless your scripts are very large.

However, there is a simple solution to avoid this. Just have something like this at the bottom of your base template

```
    <!-- footer HTML -->
    {% block page_js %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And then in each individual page you can include something like this (with as many on-page and/or externally-loaded scripts as necessary):

```
{% block page_js %}
<script>// some custom JS for this page only</script>
<script src="js/for/this/page.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your footer HTML into its own file and then add the `{% include 'footer.html' %}` in the templates where you need the footer HTML to appear. That way in future you will only need to edit footer.html when you wish to change something in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `base.html` common for all other pages. You have some JS which are common for all pages.

So you can just tweak `base.html` something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="footer">
       Footer info
    </div>
   <!---here include all JS-->
</body>
```

Comment: No, JS is not common for all pages. In fact it is different for all pages

Comment: then keep footer section in base.html